# Proof of Stability of parabolic-like Convolutional Residual Neural Networks

Tags: proof-explanation, stability-in-odes, neural-networks, stability-theory

I am trying to understand a recent publication by Lars Ruthotto and Eldad Haber called [Deep Neural Networks motivated by Partial Differential Equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.04272) published in the Journal of Mathematical Imaging and Vision.

In this paper, the authors derive a *continuous interpretation* of (Convolutional) Residual Neural Networks by seeing ResNet structures as a forward Euler discretization of an initial value problem.

---

In the following, I try to provide a straight forward introduction to the paper and derive the equation I do not understand.

We have following notation:

- training data: $\mathbf{Y} = [\mathbf{y}_1, \mathbf{y}_2, \dots, \mathbf{y}_s]^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times s} $
- true labels:  $\mathbf{C} = [\mathbf{c}_1, \mathbf{c}_2, \dots, \mathbf{c}_s]^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times s}$
- weight vector: $\mathbf{\theta} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{\theta}^{(1)} & \mathbf{\theta}^{(2)} & \mathbf{\theta}^{(3)} 
  \end{bmatrix}^\top$
- linear Operators: $\mathbf{K}_1(\cdot) \in \mathbb{R}^{\tilde{w} \times n}$ and $\mathbf{K}_2(\cdot) \in \mathbb{R}^{w_{\mathrm{out}} \times n}$

  - $\tilde{w}$ and $w_{\mathrm{out}}$ denote the width of the layer
- activation function $\sigma: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (component-wise)
- normalization layer $\mathcal{N}$ (will be ignored)

The authors provide a general formulation of a layer as follows,

$$\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{\theta}, \mathbf{Y}) = \mathbf{K}_2(\mathbf{\theta^{(3)}}) \sigma \left( \mathcal{N} (\mathbf{K}_1(\mathbf{\theta^{(1)}} \mathbf{Y}),\mathbf{\theta^{(2)}}) \right) \, .$$
For simplicity, we will assume a symmetric version
$$\mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{sym}}(\mathbf{\theta}, \mathbf{Y}) = -\mathbf{K}(\mathbf{\theta^{(3)}}) \sigma \left( \mathbf{K}(\mathbf{\theta^{(1)}} \mathbf{Y})) \right) \, ,$$
where $K_2 = -K_1^\top$ and $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{Y})=\mathbf{Y}$. The propagation of a ResNet layer then is given by
$$\begin{align}
\tag{1} \label{1} \mathbf{Y}_{j+1} = \mathbf{Y}_{j} + \mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{sym}}(\mathbf{\theta}^{(j)}, \mathbf{Y}_j), \quad \text{for} \ j=0,1,\dots, N-1 \, .
 \end{align}$$
Next, they introduce the initial value problem
$$\begin{align} \tag{2} \label{2} \partial_t \mathbf{Y}(\mathbf{\theta}, t) = &\mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{sym}}(\mathbf{\theta}(t), \mathbf{Y}(t)), \ \text{for}\ t \in (0,T] \\
\mathbf{Y}(\mathbf{\theta},0) = &\mathbf{Y}_0 \, , \end{align}
$$
which then is discretized by the forward Euler method (stepsize $h=1$) to obtain equation (\ref{1}).
Furthermore, a definition of stability of ODEs/PDEs is given as follows:

"Here, we say that the forward propagation in equation (\ref{1}) is stable if
there is a constant $M > 0$ independent of T such that
$$ \begin{align} \tag{3} \label{3} \vert \vert \mathbf{Y}(\mathbf{\theta},T) - \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}(\mathbf{\theta},T) \vert \vert_{\mathrm{F}} \leq M \vert \vert \mathbf{Y}_0 - \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_0 \vert \vert_{\mathrm{F}}\text{"}  \, . \end{align}$$
$\vert \vert \cdot \vert \vert_{\mathrm{F}}$ denotes the Frobenius norm. Now, after having a continuous interpretation of the residual neural network, they prove the stability of that network as follows:

**Theorem.** If the activation function $\sigma$ is monotonically
non-decreasing, then the forward propagation through a
parabolic CNN satisfies eq. (\ref{3}).

***Proof.*** First, we show that $\mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{sym}}(\mathbf{\theta},t)$ is a monotone operator. Let $\mathbf{Y}$ and $\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}$ be the
solutions of eq. (\ref{2}) for the initial values $\mathbf{Y}_0$, $\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_0$, respectively. Note that for all $t\in (0,T]$, we have

$$ \begin{align} -(\sigma (\mathbf{K}(t) \mathbf{Y}) - \sigma (\mathbf{K}(t) \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}), \mathbf{K}(t) (\mathbf{Y}- \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}) \leq 0 \end{align} \, . $$

Where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the inner product. The inequality follows from the monotonicity of $\sigma$. From this it follows that

$$ \begin{align} \tag{4} \label{4} \partial_t \vert\vert \mathbf{Y}(t) - \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}(t) \vert\vert_{\mathrm{F}}^2 \leq 0 \, . \end{align} $$

Integrating this inequality from $[0,T]$ yields stability as defined above. $\square$

**Question 1:** I do not see how eq. (\ref{4}) is connected to the above equation. Furthermore, I do not know how to apply the partial deriviate with respect to $t$ in eq. (\ref{4}), due to the Forbenius norm. This seems very essential in order to understand the proof.

**Question 2:** Another object I could not understand so far is the Jacobian of $\mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{sym}}$ with respect to the features $\mathbf{Y}$, which is given by

$$ \begin{align} \mathbf{J}_{\mathbf{Y}} \mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{sym}} =  - \mathbf{K} \operatorname{diag}(\sigma'(\mathbf{K}(\mathbf{\theta}) \mathbf{Y}))\mathbf{K}(\mathbf{\theta}) \, . \end{align} $$

How does one obtain the above Jacobian?